# Why the page refresh onClick even by implementing e.preventDefault() in Next/React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a function that retrieves the date selected from the UI calendar and adds it to Firestore. The function works perfectly. The only issue that I encounter is that once I click on a button to add the data the page gets refreshed automatically even though I implemented e.preventDefault inside the function that it's called onClick event. When I debugged, I found that the page doesn't refresh when I uncommented the firebase functions to set the data (please check the code below)

```
// Reference to the collection
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("Dates");

// Function to add the selected date to the database.
    const addDatetoDataBase = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        let newDataObj = {date: selectedDataFormatted, id: uuidv4()};
        // when uncommenting the code below the page doesn't get refreshed
        ref.doc(newDataObj.id).set(newDataObj)
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("Date has been added to the database");
                })
                .catch((err)=> {
                    console.log("Error, Something went wrong");
                }); 
        
    }

    // button to add the trigger the onClick event
    <button type="text" className="btn" onClick={addDatetoDataBase}>add the current date</button>
```

am I a missing something?

Comment: maybe it is because you didn't close double quotation ?

Comment: Which quotations ? Inside the button? I have them closed I just fixed now for the post

Comment: Are you sure about changing the button type to button and still not working?

Comment: The problem occurred due to something else that I have in the code. I fixed it and now it works. Thank everybody for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that : you entered the wrong type attribute of button

Use this:

```
<button type="button"
 className="btn" onClick={addDatetoDataBase}>
 add the current date</button>
```

Instead of:

```
<button type="text"
 className="btn" onClick={addDatetoDataBase}>
 add the current date</button>
```

Comment: I did change the type from text to button. But it didn't solve the problem...